# Playframework - display Json in a view

Tags: json, playframework, view

i'm facing to the compilation error "unspecified value parameter content" when i try to send json node to a view. The error occurs on the line 3 of bo.scala.html.

Thanks for helping

in my controller - Application.java

```
//send jsonNode to view table 
public static Result showReportsUniverses() throws SDKException {
    ArrayList<BiObjectsInfos> boobjects = BiFunctions.getReportsUniverses(user, 
            password, cms, apsAuthType);
    return ok(bo.render(Json.toJson(boobjects)));  
}
```

My routes

```
GET      /boobjects                 controllers.Application.showReportsUniverses()
```

My view - bo.scala.html -

```
@()

@table(){
    // boobjects handles the JsonNode boobjects
    <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/boobjects.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <tbody id= "boobjects" \>
        <tr>
            <th>Reports</th>
            <th>Universes</th>
}
```

My view - table.scala.html -

```
@(content : Html)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bla</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="@routes.Assets.at("css/table.css")" >
        <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>    
   </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            @content
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

my coffee script boobjects.js

```
$ ->
   $.get "/boobjects", (boobjects) ->
    $.each boobjects, (index, boObj) ->
      $("#boobjects").append $("<tr>")
      $("#boobjects").append $("<td>").text boObj.si_name
      $("#boobjects").append $("<td>").text boObj.universe_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return ok(boobjects.render(toJson(boobjects)));
```

should read

```
return ok(boobjects.render(Json.toJson(boobjects)));
```

Comment: thx for your answer, i tried "return ok(boobjects.render(Json.toJson(boobjects)));" but i got a compilation error : not suitable method found for toJson(ArrayList <BiObjectsInfos>). here is my import "import play.api.libs.json.Json"

Comment: Hi Ryan, I edit my question. i found what was wrong and corrected it " my view got the same name than the arrayList". Now i don't know what argument to use in the view so that my JsonNode been handle by the coffee script. Thx

Comment: Could somebody tell me what wrong with my problem ? maybe i didn't expose clearly my question ?